# Swift Convert A String-As-An-Array, To An Array Of Strings

Tags: arrays, string, swift

I have a string:

`"["word1","word2"]"`

And I want a simple way to convert it to an actual `[String]`.

All the other questions I could dig up on there were about converting int strings to arrays.

I tried doing

`Array(arrayLiteral: "["word1","word2"]")`

But I get

`["[\"word1\",\"word2\"]"]`

Manually cleaning up the edges and removing the slashes seems like I'm doing something very wrong.

I'm curious if there's a simple way to convert a an array of strings as a string into an array of strings.

i.e. Convert `"["word1","word2"]"` to `["word1","word2"]`

**Solution** (Thanks to @Eric D)

```
    let data = stringArrayString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    var stringsArray:[String]!

    do
    {
        stringsArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String]
    } catch
    {
        print()
    }

    print("Array is \(stringsArray)")
```

Comment: Where is the string comming from ?

Comment: My app uses Cordova, so this is a command coming from a Javascript interface.

Comment: Looks like JSON try using SwiftyJSON to parse it

Comment: @LeoDabus I could use SwiftyJSON but I am curious if theres a quick way built into swift where I can move directly to a string array from a string formatted as an array

Comment: There's stuff built in to Foundation, but not built into the Swift standard library as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encode your "string array" to data, then decode this data as JSON to a Swift Array.

Like this, for example:

```
let source = "[\"word1\",\"word2\"]"

guard let data = source.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    arrayOfStrings = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String] else {
        fatalError()
}

print(arrayOfStrings)  // ["word1", "word2"]
print(arrayOfStrings[1])  // "word2"
```

Comment: Interesting I've not seen this syntax before! Could you name what `guard let data = source.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding),
    arrayOfStrings = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])` is called? I'd like to read up on this

Comment: It's called a "guard statement" and you can read about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID525 in the "Early exit" section of "Control Flow". It's an alternative to `if let` that lets you use the unwrapped value in the current scope. It's very convenient. :)

Comment: Very cool! Might want to update your answer to include the catch ;).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with comments above, I'd probably use a JSON parser. Failing that (or if you can't for some reason), I do not know of any built-in way; you'd have to do it manually. I'd do something like:

```
extension String {
    func stringByTrimmingFirstAndLast() -> String {
        let startIndex = self.startIndex.successor()
        let endIndex = self.endIndex.predecessor()
        return self.substringWithRange( startIndex..<endIndex )
    }
}

let str = "[\"word1\",\"word2\"]"
let array = str
    .stringByTrimmingFirstAndLast()
    .componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    .map { string in
        return string.stringByTrimmingFirstAndLast()
    }
```